CakePHP5 - How can I migrate findAuth from CakePHP3
I'm about to migrate my old CakePHP3 App to 5.
It is quite difficult.
I try to entend the Auth Identity which is actually limited tu users table field with associated data.
In 3 i use FindAuth, but it seems to not be ...
Thanks for your help
I try this :
//Translate to 3.X
public function findAuth(Query $query, array $options): Query
{
    return $query->contain(['Roles', 'Agences']);
}

//Pick on Cakephp4 forum
public function findForAuthentication(Query $query, array $options): Query
{
    return $query->contain(['Roles', 'Agences']);
}

but none of them work

Have you seen the finder option in the resolver configuration that you pass when setting up the identifier?

For these tasks, you now need to use CakePHP Policy classes.
